# mysql - How to format numbers based on the user's format

Tags: mysql, formatting

I want to display the numbers based on the format of the user.
Like for example, the number is `123456789` and the format is `999-999-999`, I want to display it like `123-456-789`, if the format is `99-99-99-999` then it will show `12-34-56-789`.

I tried to find some problems similar to mine but I only find the static formats like `(999) - 999 - 999`

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(123456789, 3), '-', MID(123456789, 4, 3), '-', RIGHT(123456789, 3));
```

but its only for 9 numbers and it's static.

I expect the numbers to be displayed based on the dynamic format

Comment: Do you have any other technologies at your disposal (php,python..)?

Comment: i also use php but I think its no use for my problem

Comment: Try searching for mysql output masking.

Comment: I also tried that, I'll look for some answers again, thank you.